# How do I specify an account in the Related To field in a custom Global Action Predefined Field Value?

Tags: account, fields, formula-field, global-actions

I have created a custom Global Action, and am trying to predefine a value for the Related To field. Related To appears in the picklist of available fields for Predefined Values, so it appears this is possible, but I can't figure out what syntax/formula to use to specify a specific account. Thanks!

Syntax I've tried so far:

```
(Account(AccountName))
Account(AccountName)
Account.AccountName
```

And a number of other variations. I've also tried using the ID of the account pulled from the URL.

Comment: It might be helpful if you show some of the syntax you have tried.  Might get an answer quicker.

Comment: I just tried a straight ID, and an ID in quotes and neither worked..

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to specify both the target item and also the object type (Account)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things going on here:

1. To predefine a lookup field in a Publisher Action, you need to pass in an ID Field. So, if this were going to work, you would put Account.Id. As @LaceySnr posts, there doesn't seem to be a way to pass an actual record ID into the field. *(However, note that there is an acknowledged (in Twitter by the PMs, not on Known Issues) bug whereby if you pass an ID into a lookup field and that field is displayed on the Action's layout, the field doesn't show as prepopulated, but it does create the record with the correct relationship if you don't alter the field.)*
2. A Global Action doesn't get any of the context from what you're currently viewing, there's no "automatic relationship between the record that’s created and any other record".[*](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_global_actions.htm&language=en_US) If you want a publisher action to create a task or event that's related to the Account, either use the standard Publisher Actions on Account, or create custom actions on any objects from which you might want to create the action, and prepopulate the RelatedTo with an Account Id-returning formula there.